# Date input field format

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I have TextCtrl field in which user should enter the date in format dd.mm.yyyy
I wanna force him to do it in that format, so is it possible to have something like this 
* * . * * . * * * * in text field and when he enters numbers, those numbers replaces *.
So he doesnt need to type dots , only numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `Masked Edit Control` see the wxPython demo for a number of examples.

Comment: Thx, it works, I have one more question. In TextCtrl I could use method SetSelction(-1,-1) to select all text in the text field, but it seems that MaskedEditControl doesnt have that method. Is there another way to select all text in MaskedEditControl?

Comment: Just use `SelectAll()`